# Duplication form groups with jquery clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a site that allows users to add multiple criteria to a specific subscription.

Heres my form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Create Subscription</h2>
        <form action="/subscription" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Subscription Nickname</label>
                <input type="text" name="nickname" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Vehicle Make</label>
                <select name="make" class="form-control makes">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <?php if($makes): ?>
                        <?php foreach($makes as $make => $v): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $make ?>"><?= $make ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </select>
            </div>


            <h2>What parts do you want to be notified for? </h2>
            <div class="components-list">
                <div class="row components-tree" id="part1">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control years" name="parts[0][year]">
                                <option value="0">Year</option>
                                <option value="*">All</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control models" name="parts[0][model]">
                                <option value="0">Model</option>
                                <option value="*">All</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control engines" name="parts[0][engine]">
                                <option value="0">Engine</option>
                                <option value="*">All</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control comp-fams" name="parts[0][comp_family]">
                                <option value="0">Comp. Family</option>
                                <option value="*">All</option>
                                <?php foreach($families as $family): ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $family['comp_family'] ?>"><?= $family['comp_family'] ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control components" name="parts[0][component]">
                                <option value="0">Component</option>
                                <option value="*">All</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success clone">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger remove">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The years are populated when a user selects a make, the models are loaded when a user selects a year, engines are loaded when a users selects model and so forth. I need to be able to add more years/model/engine/comp fam/comp dynamically so I know I could just clone the closest `component-tree`

```
$('.clone').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.components-list').append($(this).closest('.component-tree').clone());
});
```

but I am stuck as to how to change the index from `name="parts[0][year]"` to `name="parts[index][year]"` dynamically when a user clones them as well as keep the previous value.

Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Comment: did you consider leaving the index value out completely `parts[][component]`?

Comment: If I leave the index number out then you cannot organize them into groups.

Comment: why not, they will end up being indexed the same in array at server. You will need to use a regex on name if you want to have index values otherwise

Comment: Well looking at the form I need for components-tree row to be considered one group. When you dont index them then they cannot be grouped together and you have to build in extra logic to group them before being able to work with them and store them into the database.

Comment: but they will be indexed by position in form even without expicitely setting index, did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried it before responding

Comment: Unfortunate, has always worked for me